Does the argument by analogy in favor of the existence of other minds lead to solipsism?
https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/other-minds/#ArguAnal
I can't understand the article. Here it is said that the argument by analogy inevitably leads to solipsism. Then it is said that the argument by analogy is a way to avoid epistemological solipsism but contradicts conceptual solipsism.
What does this all mean, and what are the practical consequences of using an argument by analogy to justify your belief in the existence of other minds?

I'm not surprised you cannot make sense of it, as it is nonsense from start to finish.

So the article itself is nonsense?

Metaphorical analogy is actually extremely subtle, deep, pervasive and hidden, which is much larger in scope than induction or abduction. It could be said all metaphysics is just metaphors, and thus in this sense it could lead to solipsism if solipsism happens to be the correct thesis of metaphysics...
